# Android MultipartEntity image upload with EXIF data

Tags: android

I'm trying to upload images to the server with EXIF data. Here's my code:

```
File file = new File(filePath);

FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
byte[] b = new byte[1024];

int bytesRead;
while ((bytesRead = fis.read(b)) != -1) {
    bos.write(b, 0, bytesRead);
}
byte[] bytes = bos.toByteArray();

MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
ByteArrayBody bin = new ByteArrayBody(bytes, "image.jpg");
reqEntity.addPart("file", bin);
postMethod = new HttpPost(url);
postMethod.setEntity(reqEntity);
HttpResponse reply = httpClient.execute(postMethod);
```

Initially, I created a FileBody straight from the file, but that wasn't preserving EXIF data either.
The filePath is the path I provided the Camera activity with to save the full size image taken by the user.

So, my question is, how do I upload images without losing the EXIF information?

Comment: If you upload the file as a byte stream, the EXIF data is guaranteed to be in there. Have you tried dumping the image to disk on your web server and checking whether the EXIF data is present?

Comment: @SimonMcKenzie So you're saying, the way I'm doing it now, the EXIF info is guaranteed to be there?
I would have to ask the server team what's going on then. Perhaps the problem is not in my code, but it's that they're stripping the info on their side.

Comment: Yes - EXIF's just part of the file data.